# wpf datagrid how to implement swipe down to select items swipe up to invert selection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

wpf datagrid how to implement swipe down to select items swipe up to invert selection,I've tried the following codes and none of them work, I know it should be done with these events(TouchDown, TouchUp,TouchMove),I'd like to implement something like the long press down to select an item and long press up to reverse the selection on a cell phone.

```
private Point touchStartPoint;
    private Point touchEndPoint;
    private DataGridRow touchedStartRow;
    private DataGridRow touchedEndRow;
    private int nextIndex = 0;
    private int previousIndex = 0;

    private void DataGridRow_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        touchStartPoint = e.GetTouchPoint(dgBookList).Position;
        var element = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
        while (element != null && !(element is DataGridRow))
        {
            element = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element) as FrameworkElement;
        }

        touchedStartRow = element as DataGridRow;
        previousIndex = dgBookList.Items.IndexOf(touchedStartRow.Item);
    }

    private void DataGridRow_TouchUp(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        touchEndPoint = e.GetTouchPoint(dgBookList).Position;
        var element = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
        while (element != null && !(element is DataGridRow))
        {
            element = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element) as FrameworkElement;
        }

        touchedEndRow = element as DataGridRow;
        previousIndex = dgBookList.Items.IndexOf(touchedEndRow.Item);

        var direction = touchEndPoint.Y - touchStartPoint.Y;

        if (direction > 0)
        {
            // swipe down

            if (nextIndex < dgBookList.Items.Count)
            {
                var nextItem = dgBookList.Items[nextIndex] as ReservedItemInfo; 
                if (nextItem != null)
                {
                    nextItem.IsSelected = true;
                }
            }
            nextIndex++;
        }
        else if (direction < 0)
        {
            // swipe up
            if (previousIndex >= 0)
            {
                var previousItem = dgBookList.Items[previousIndex] as ReservedItemInfo; 
                if (previousItem != null)
                {
                    previousItem.IsSelected = false;
                }
            }
            previousIndex--;
        }
        nextIndex = 0;
        previousIndex = 0;
    }

    private void DataGridRow_TouchMove(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        //var touchEndPoint = e.GetTouchPoint(dgBookList).Position;
        touchEndPoint = e.GetTouchPoint(dgBookList).Position;
        var element = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
        while (element != null && !(element is DataGridRow))
        {
            element = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element) as FrameworkElement;
        }

        touchedEndRow = element as DataGridRow;
        previousIndex = dgBookList.Items.IndexOf(touchedEndRow.Item);

        var direction = touchEndPoint.Y - touchStartPoint.Y;

        if (direction > 0)
        {
            // swipe down

            if (nextIndex < dgBookList.Items.Count)
            {
                var nextItem = dgBookList.Items[nextIndex] as ReservedItemInfo; 
                if (nextItem != null)
                {
                    nextItem.IsSelected = true;
                }
            }
            nextIndex++;
        }
        else if (direction < 0)
        {
            // swipe up
            if (previousIndex >= 0)
            {
                var previousItem = dgBookList.Items[previousIndex] as ReservedItemInfo; 
                if (previousItem != null)
                {
                    previousItem.IsSelected = false;
                }
            }
            previousIndex--;
        }
        nextIndex = 0;
        previousIndex = 0;
    }
```